# Change $\min \Re(x^*(A+A^*)x)$ to $\max\alpha$ problem

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers

I have an optimization problem where the cost function is $\Re(x^*(A+A^*)x)$, where $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Instead of minimizing $\Re(x^*(A+A^*)x)$, I would like to maximize angle $\alpha$, where $0\leq\alpha\leq\pi$.

[image]
When $\Re(x^*(A+A^*)x)>0,$ I can change $\min \Re(x^*(A+A^*)x)$ with $\max \cos^{-1}[\Re(x^*(A+A^*)x)]$. However, I have problem when $\Re(x^*(A+A^*)x)\leq0.$ Please help me to rewrite the optimization problem in terms of angle.